# Only have acces when admin

Tags: php

I want to make a page where I can sign up people. However, normal people can't sign up, only administrators. I have it working and made a login page, but now I need to block people that aren't admins from the sign up page. I currently have:

```
if (isset($_POST['isAdmin'])) {
    $userid = $_POST['isAdmin'];

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM staff_users WHERE isAdmin = '$userid'";
    $result = $dbc->query($query);
    {
        $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $userid;
    }
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    # redirect to the login page
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/staff');
    exit();
}

if ($_SESSION['isAdmin'] == 'N') {
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/isnotstaff');
    exit();
}
```

Also I currently have a database setup like this http://prntscr.com/lnauru
The problem is that people can still access the page; it doesn't matter if there is "Y" or "N"

Comment: It looks like you have some stuff backwards. Example, ` $userid = $_POST['isAdmin'];` shouldn't this be set to the userid and not the `$_POST['isAdmin']` boolean? Also, `$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $userid;` should be `$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $_POST['isAdmin'];` correct?

Comment: @tom-keuper: Edits were made to the text to improve readability. If I changed the meaning, please feel free to [edit this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53488243/edit) yourself.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injections with that code, you should ***ALWAYS*** use prepared statements

Comment: 1. There is no mention what driver you are using; mysqli or PDO? 2. You do not use `$result` anywhere. 3. `$_SESSION['isAdmin']` comes directly from `$_POST['isAdmin']`, not from DB

Comment: I am using mysqli and I have my db config file somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['isAdmin'])){
$userid     = $_POST['isAdmin'];

$query      = "SELECT * FROM staff_users WHERE userName = '$userid' AND isAdmin = 'Y'";
$result     = $dbc->query($query);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt > 0){
    $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $userid;
}
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])){
    # redirect to the login page
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/staff');
    exit();
}

if ($_SESSION['isAdmin']=='N')
{
    header('Location: https://mywebsite.com/isnotstaff');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: How can you be sure that OP uses mysqli? How do you know his schema?

Comment: the screenshot is from PHPmyadmin, so i guessed he has mysqli connection somewhere in code.

Comment: It could be PDO.

Comment: You are right. In that case replace the $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; with  $row_cnt = $result->rowCount();

Comment: Why? `$result` is a result in itself! `if ($result) {...` is enough.

Comment: It doesnt work it will do the same as what i have now, the page doesnt show any errors and everyone can acces it